# why no sfeika deyoma for sfiras haomer?

Tags: chutz-laaretz, sefirat-ha-omer, safek

Most or all Jewish holidays have an extra day in the Diaspora, to accomodate for sfeike deyoma, so why do we not count two numbers each day of sfira?

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Yosef Dov Soloveichik zt'l is quoted as saying that "today is 12 ... or 13" is not considered counting!

Others suggest that *sfeika deyoma* as we know it today was pretty much only accepted vis-a-vis observing a day as *yomtov*.

Comment: Who are these "others"? And what is "pretty much"?